# Multiple cursor markers in Eclipse text editor

Tags: eclipse, plugins, marker, text-editor

I am developing a plug-in for Eclipse. I have to develop a Java text editor which allows several users to write the code at the same time, the same way as in Google Docs. But I came across the following problem: the text editor has to show the cursor position of the other users who are coding in same Java document. In other words, I want to place a marker in the text editor content ([see this image that shows what I'm trying to implement](http://cache.gawker.com/assets/images/lifehacker/2010/04/cursor-chasing-th.png)).

I've already looked `IMarker`, but `IMarker` is placed on the text editor's vertical ruler, which is not what I want. Can I use this class? If not, what other class should I use?

The other idea of mine was to insert a JTable in the text editor, but I couldn't find the way how to do that. Is this a right approach, or I'm wrong?

Stack Overflow Gods, please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has two different concepts for managing extra information related to files: markers and annotations. Annotations are related to a single editor instance, and their appearance can be customized with a corresponding extension point; markers are used to store extra information permanently (and additionally an annotation can be set up for that reason).

I think, you need to use annotations, as markers are too heavyweight for a real-time collaboration. For future reference, see the [Annotations in the Eclipse Help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/editors_annotations.htm); and some time ago [I have written a blog post](http://cubussapiens.hu/2010/11/markers-and-annotations-in-eclipse-for-error-feedback/) that describes an automatic translation (and customization) of markers to annotations.

Comment: thank you for answer. after i try it, and i will ask way for solve problem. your answer is helped me.